# How to create video stream from a sequence of bitmaps with Flash/wowza

Tags: flash, video, streaming, bitmapdata, wowza

Please suggest, googling failed.

I need to create video stream from a sequence of bitmaps (i.e Bitmapdata.draw() ).
Is it possible? Seems like I can put anything into Netstream.send(), but should I encode the images manually, or there's some framework feature?
I plan to use wowza server as backend.
Any links to examples would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop researching streaming servers (like Wowza) and start researching encoders, like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).  Streaming servers are for delivering content, not encoding content.  The content you are streaming needs to be encoded into fairly well defined formats/codecs/standards.  EG. h264.